# Define dependency between a standalone script and web app during installation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a standalone script which works with Google Sheets. I need to have an URL to which I can send a small chunk of data from another service and this data is required for my script to work.

So far I came up with the following solution. I create a separate web app script which will provide me with URL. Then, I send data to the app, it saves it on the Google Drive of the user and later my standalone script reads it.

However, I don't understand at this point how I should bind my standalone script with the web app, so when the user installs the standalone it would have everything working.

Will appreciate any comments!

Comment: Google Apps Script projects aren't installable software, they are stored and ran on the cloud. What do you mean by "when the user installs the standalone"? Do you mean when they make a copy?

Comment: App script is not a standalone, if you want to access script in other apps and others people publicly deploy your script.

Comment: @Ruben by installing I mean when the user gets or adds the add-on from the Add-Ons -> Get add-ons menu. Basically, I want to publish the standalone script and web app and when the user adds the standalone script to its Google Sheets I want to be sure that somehow it prompts  him to trigger the web app, so web app would ask permissions to write to Google Drive.

Comment: @NitinDhomse There are different type of app scripts according to Google docs [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) I was referring to one of them, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Ohh, Please read the spreadsheet by its 'id' (openById) and use that spreadsheet instance in the whole your standalone script, there is no need of special kind of dependency.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I'm not sure that I understand your suggestion. As far as I know when user installs the standalone script it will be present in its all Google Sheets. What I need is that my standalone script has a specific logic which requires specific info from another service per one spreadsheet. The problem here that I don't know how to send this info to the script, since I don't have any URL which script may accept. Thus, I want create a web app which will have this URL and will create some *.txt file on the drive when the service sends the request.

Comment: Deploy all your scripts bounded / standalone so that you will get the public URLs and they can communicate publicly with each other, in which script you want to get some information from another script use doGet(e) / doPost(e) method. read parameters as var paramName = e.parameter['paramName'], send data using urlFetch() in calling script, refer the Google's docs to implement this

Comment: @NitinDhomse that's exactly what I want to do. However, it's still not clear to me how user should allow my web app script to write to its Google Drive when it installs only the standalone script.

Comment: The script is going to write the data (.txt file) on the Drive (of script owner) which is authenticated and authorized by owner already, if you want to provide some extra security then you can use any username / password like mechanism or any token, maintain those info in particular sheet and verify against that user or app is valid or not, your any web app will just invoke that script and write the file, I'll suggest you to walk through the docs and try to implements the things that will help you to understand the functionality.

Comment: @NitinDhomse There are two scripts the first it's standalone the second it's web app. User adds or installs only the standalone, which doesn't write to drive, only reads. The second, web app should accept the requests from third party service and then write this info to drive so the first one would read it.